# Proof of an inequality involiving hyperbolic function

Tags: inequality

How can I get a proof of the following inequality:
$$\frac{x}{\sinh^{-1}(x)}\lt\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}?$$ for $x\gt 0$
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as $\frac{\sinh(y)}{y}<\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}$ for $y=\sinh^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score 0):

You can bring everything to the left side and make common denominators. Replace the hyperbolic functions with their equivalencies, i.e. the e-power representation and the ln term for the hyperbolic sine and its inverse respectively. Since x>0 all original terms will be positive, so your inequality sign won't change. Now check out the numerator. It contains an x² term as well as an e-power, subject to a minus sign. If x goes to infinity, who is going to win? The quadratic term or the e-power? Oh yeah, the e-power is of course also subject to a multiplication with that ln term. But if x goes to infinity, what happens to that ln term? Can you finish it from here?